# How can I identify all background apps currently running?

Tags: 8.1, apps, battery, background-tasks, battery-saver

My battery drain has jumped from 2.3% per hour to 6.1% per hour and the screenn is as dim as I can possibly make it and only WiFi and Cellular are currently running.  Essentially nothing has changed since yesterday except I went on a shopping spree and d/led 18 new apps.
I've gone through Battery Sense and looked at each app and turned off all background for those that have the option.  Many have "App in background" greater than 1% but NO option to stop them from running in background.
So I want to see all background apps currently running to see which is the bad app I've downloaded and remove it.

Is there a third party task manager that anyone recommends as Battery Sense is just not enough and I'm not going to accept a 4% jump in battery drain and I'm irked that Windows 8.1 Phone eliminated the background option under Applications in the settings and doesn't come with a task manager.  Yes I *could* pull each of the 18 apps off one at a time and shut down the phone 18 times then restart it and check battery drain but that's time consuming and inefficient when a background task identifying app would go straight to the heart of the matter.

Searching for "process manager" or "task manager" at the Windows store only turns up life event handling software and no useful OS utilities.

Comment: See also: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/689/106, http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/5429/106 and http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/11333/106

Comment: I'll check the sync but this email account was created only for this phone and gets no emails.  
Looks like background tasks get 25 seconds of running but not sure how often as the webpage link is 404'd.

"Settings -> Applications -> background tasks." from that answer doesn't exist in Windows Phone 8.1 on my Lumia 975.  
Is the option removed from all Windows 8.1 or just my model?

Comment: On 8.1 it was moevd into **Battery Saver**, where you can tap an app to disable in the background

Comment: The email was set to d/l every 30 minutes.
Bluetooth is off and this phone has no NFC and syncing is turned off.

OK the third link your provided gave a great explanation and I realize that one of the culprits could be TuneIn Radio that is paused (no audio), missing from the suspended (back arrow) list but somehow still running a background process even though I went into it's Battery Sense settings and turned that off.
Still at 4.3% drain per hour which is up from 2.3% of last month.

Going to d/l this app that your third link provided:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2684808

Comment: Upon d/ling and trying to install [XAP APP] Process Viewer, I get "Can't install company app: There's a problem with this company app. Contact  blah, blah, blah.."

This isn't a root user issue message, is it?

Answer (score -1):

try this, press and hold the back arrow key at the bottom part of the phone, and you will see the running applications in the background. You can just slide them down or tap on the " X " mark at the upper right part of the application to close it.

Comment: These applications are suspended, and not actually running

Comment: Right.  I know Astronomy Screen Lock is running in the background because it regularly updates it's livetile and then takes over as screen saver.  I think TrueCaller is running in background because it has to be available to identify an incoming caller.  But I was 2.3% battery drain with those two installed.